# Almost Euclidean balls and support functions from High-Dimensional Probability (Roman Vershynin)

Tags: probability, analysis, convex-hulls

I tried to solve Exercise 11.3.2 (Almost Euclidean balls and support functions) from High-Dimensional Probability (Roman Vershynin) and find out that there is a mistake in first part (I think it's a mistake) and reformulate it

<
(i) Let $V \subset R^m$ be a bounded set. Show that $B^m_2 \subset \conv (V) \subset \closure {B^m_2}$ for every if and only if
$$
 \sup_{x \in V} <x,y> =  \lVert y  \rVert_2  \text{  for all  }  y \in R^m.
$$
(ii)
Let $V \subset R^m$ be a bounded set and $r_-,r_+ \geq 0$. Show that the inclusion
$$
  r_- B^m_2 \subset \conv(V) \subset r_+ \closure{B^m_2} 
$$
holds if and only if
$$
 r_- \lVert y  \rVert_2 \leq \sup_{x \in V} <x,y> \leq  r_+\lVert y  \rVert_2 \text{  for all }  y \in  R^m.
$$

Where $B^m_2$ is open Euclidean ball with 1 radian and 0 center $(\{x \in R^m : \lVert x \rVert_2 < 1 \})$ and $\closure{B^m_2}$ is it's closure $(\{x \in R^m : \lVert x \rVert_2 \leq 1 \})$.

> 

I solved (i) but not the (ii). I hope someone can help me with it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, [here is a MathJaX tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to fix the formatting of your post. Also you are more likely to receive an answer if you show how you've solved (i) and what you've tried to solving (ii).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reformulated the exercise by adding closedness assumption to $V$ for both (a) and (b). In addition, for part (a) we should have $\text{conv}(V) = B_2^m$ instead of $V = B_2^m$. I'm assuming $B_2^m$ is closed, which I believe is a consistent notation in Vershynin's book.

That $r_- B_2^m \subset \text{conv}(V)\subset r_+ B_2^m$ implies the inequalities is trivial. So, let's show the converse. The inequalities are equivalent to

$$
r_- \leq \sup_{x\in V}\langle x,\theta \rangle \leq r_+ \text{ for all $y\in \mathcal{S}^{m-1}$}
$$

Suppose $\text{conv}(V)\setminus r_+ B_2^m \neq \emptyset$. Then there exists $x_0 \in V \setminus r_+ B_2^m$ indicating

$$
r_+ < \langle x_0, \frac{x_0}{\|x_0\|}\rangle \leq \sup_{x\in V} \langle x, \frac{x_0}{\|x_0\|}\rangle \leq r_+
$$

This is a contradiction.

Next, we show $r_- B_2^m \subset \text{conv}(V)$.

Let $\lambda_\theta$ be $\sup \{\lambda \geq 0 \text{ such that } \lambda \theta \in \text{conv}(V)\}$. It suffices to prove $\lambda_\theta \geq r_-$ for all $\theta \in \mathcal{S}^{m-1}$.

Suppose there exists $\theta_0 \in \mathcal{S}^{m-1}$ such that $\lambda_{\theta_0}< r_-$. Take a hyperplane $H$ which is tangent to $\text{conv}(V)$ at the point $x_0 = \lambda_{\theta_0}\theta_0$. Then choose $\theta_1\in \mathcal{S}^{m-1}$ so that the hyperplane $H$ is expressed as $\{\langle x-x_0, \theta_1 \rangle=0\}$.

From our construction, we may assume $V \in \{\langle x-x_0, \theta_1 \rangle \leq 0\}$.

Then, we have
$$
r_- \leq \sup_{x\in V}\langle x, \theta_1\rangle \leq \langle x_0, \theta_1\rangle \leq \|x_0\| = \langle x_0, \theta_0 \rangle < r_-
$$
This is a contradiction.

The first inequality is due to the assumption and the second is due to $V \in \{\langle x-x_0, \theta_1 \rangle \leq 0\}$. For the third inequality, note that $\langle x_0, \theta_1\rangle$ is the distance from the origin to the hyperplane $H$, so it must be smaller than $\|x_0\|$.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If it was helpful, please vote and accept my answer.

Comment: I accept your answer, but I can't vote it. System said that i have to have at least 15 reputation. And i have some extra questions and hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.
1) Is the only reason of clossednes assumption of V obtaining max instead of sum? I mean fact that we can assume that < $$ \lambda_\theta \theta $$ >is in V. 2) Is H one of the tangent hyperplans and the reason of existence such a plane is convexity of conv(V)?

Comment: Yes you are right. But, I assumed $V$ to be closed since $B_2^m$ is closed. If $r_- = r_+=1$ and $V=\text{int}(B_2^m)$, then $\text{conv}(V) = V =\text{int}(B_2^m) $ does not contain $B_2^m$. So, the statement does not make sense any more. Note that convex hull can be an open set according to the definition employed in Vershynin's book (defined in the beginning of "Appetizer".). The reason of the existence of tangent hypeplane is due to the convexity of the convex hull.